# В режиме headless на selenium при воспроизведении видео отсутствует звук

Tags: python, selenium, headless

пишу программу, которая по названию находит музыку на Ютубе и включает ее. В обычном режиме все работает корректно, но когда включаю headless, то пропадает звук. Ошибок никаких нет, проверял корректность работы, все работает как нужно, кроме звука. Как включить звук в режиме headless?
кусочек кода:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--disable-features=AudioServiceOutOfProcess")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/chromedriver',
                              options=options)


def music(data):
    driver.get(f'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={data}')
    print('перешла на сайт. жду...')
    time.sleep(5)
    user_data = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]')
    links = []
    for i in user_data:
        links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
    driver.get(links[0])
    print('включила')
```

Comment: Не видать корректного минимального примера воспроизводящего проблему.

Answer (score 0):

В режиме headless веб-драйвер работает без GUI(графического интерфейса), что означает отсутствие визуального отображения веб-страниц и звука. В этом режиме браузер выполняет все операции в фоновом режиме без взаимодействия с пользователем.Если хотите отключить GUI, то установите значение:

`options.headless = False`